# WebClass Runtime Error - 0x800A4002

Tags: asp-classic, vb6

I need to use the `WebClass` component from VB6 and when I try to create a new project in my machine (IIS Application) and execute it, it simply doesn't run. I get the error:

> WebClass Runtime (0x800A4002)
>   An unspecified error has occurred
>   \myfolder\WebClass1.ASP, line 14

I also try to compile the solution and register the DLL in windows XP but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Has someone experienced something like this before? Any help?